# How to solve a problem about anagrams

Tags: combinatorics

> How many anagrams has the word **KOMBINATOORIKA** with the condition that the $3$ letters **O** can't be next to each other.

How to get to the answer?

**My work**. So the first thing I did, was to find how many anagrams the word "KOMBINATOORIKA" has in total, with no extra conditions I got $14! / (3! 2! 2! 2!)$  as an answer. Now I try to find how many different anagram contain combination "OOO". I could subtract answer from my first answer. That would give me end result. This is the idea.

Comment: KOOOMBINATRIKA is not admitted. What about KOMBINATOORIKA? Can two Os be next to each other?

Comment: Yes there can be two 0s next to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the solution is $\frac{14!}{2^3*6}-\frac{12!}{2^3}$.

Comment: Use the hint by Robert Z.

Comment: So is this correct: $\frac{14!}{2^3*3!}-\frac{12!}{2^3}=$ 1 756 339 200, Where as what I had before was 137 214 000.

Comment: Consider total number of words with O's as a block. So number of letters is 12. Calculate the permutation which will give  number of anagrams where the three Os are adjacent. To calculate total number of anagrams use the same method as you have done but include th O's as well. Subtract the former from the latter to get the result.

Comment: It seems you have got it right. $\dfrac{14!}{2^3\cdot 3!}-\dfrac{12!}{2^3}=$

Comment: I don't understand why my first answer is not right? The reasoning seem correct?

Comment: Because you consider the O's as individual and not as a block.

Comment: I understood it now. Thanks for help

Comment: I still don't understand, We want the O's not next to each other, so that is why I considered them as individual. Also thank for the vote? Appreciate it.

Comment: ok I edited it.Ok I finally understood! you could have 2 c next to each other they are allowed!

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Consider the total number of anagrams and subtract the number of anagrams where the three Os are adjacent.

P.S. According to your work the total number of anagrams is
$$\frac{14!}{3!2!2!2!}$$
which is correct. Now we enumerate the anagrams where we consider the string OOO just as one letter.  So the number of letters decreases from $14$ to $12$ and the number of such anagrams is
$$\frac{12!}{2!2!2!}.$$
Finally we subtract this result from the first one:
$$\frac{14!}{3!2!2!2!}-\frac{12!}{2!2!2!}.$$

Comment: yes, I figured that much. First I calculated amount of all anagrams (with 3 "o" letters allowed). Then I tried to find amount of anagrams, that contains set of 3 "o"and subtract the answer from total.

It was finding the amount of anagrams, that contains set of 3 "o", that caused the problem

Comment: @GWL Please edit your question and share with us what have you found.

Comment: So the first thing I did, was to find how many anagrams the word "KOMBINATOORIKA" has in total, with no extra conditions
I got 14! / 3! 2! 2! 2! as an answer.
Now I try to find how many different anagram contain combination "OOO".
I could subtract answer from my first answer. That would give me end result. This is the idea